# Angular regex that matches a pair of words between ->

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I need a regex that matches texts with one or more lines from here:

"" (empty chain)

word1->word2

word1  ->   word2

succesives \r\s\t

\n

etc.
word1 and word 2 can be a combo of digits ; # or any symbol excepting \n.

I've proved this:

```
const expreg = new RegExp('([^"->"\n]->[^"->"\n])|(([^"->"\n]->[^"->"\n])\n)*');
```

But it also matches

word1->

second try: but it doesn't even match hello1->hello2

> ((^(\s\r\t|\n|->)^(->|\n)*->^(\s|\r|\t|\n|->)^(->|\n)*)|(^(\s|\r|\t|\n|->)^(->|\n)*->^(\s|\r|\t|\n|->)^(->|\n)*\n)|(\n)|([\s\r\t]+)|([\s\r\t]+\n))

Comment: Could you clearer about your **input text**? Put it in a block of code. And what are you trying to extract from it? This could help us understanding what you a trying to do.

Comment: Try `const expreg = /^(?:\w+(?:\s*->\s*\w+)+)?$/;` https://regex101.com/r/fZPFPP/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match 1 or more word characters, and then have a repeating part matching `->` followed by 1 or more word characters again.

The whole expression is optional to also match an empty string.

```
^(?:[^>-]+[^\S\r\n]*->[^\S\r\n]*[^>-]+)?$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/abBIj3/1)

```js
const expreg = /^(?:[^>-]+[^\S\r\n]*->[^\S\r\n]*[^>-]+)?$/m;
[
  "word1->word2",
  "",
  "word1  ->   word2",
  "my django db->my django db",
  "tds->dfds\nmy->computer",
  "word1->",
  "word1  ->   word2 ->word3"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${expreg.test(s)} "${s}"`));
```